# Can I use FileNameExtensionFilter to filter out a list of files?

Tags: java

I have a large collection with many entries: `Set<File> allFiles`.

**Is it practical** to iterate through this Set using the following algorithm? Are there better ways to do it?

```
Set<File> allFiles = // ...100,000+ entries
Set<File> filteredList = new LinkedHashSet<File>();

FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Extensions accepted", "a", "b", "c");

for (File file : allFiles) {
    if (filter.accept(file)) {
        filteredList.add(file);
    }
}
```

In case anyone is asking, the `allFiles` Set is pre-populated elsewhere, and not necessarily gleaned using the File.listFiles() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by practical you mean writeable in 5 lines in java yes it is. There is no cleaner alternatives when you want to filter a list (as opposed to languages with functional constructs like Scala and its filter method).

I personaly do not see how you could do it better, if your use case is really to filter out files with bad extensions I would do the same in Java.

If you are worried to use interfaces and classes from `javax.swing` you should not, both these classes depend only on `java.io` or `java.util.Locale` (for setting file name to lowercase according to english locale), so they are as clean as the `FilenameFilter` from `java.io`. If your deal is really to filter according to case insensitive extension you should definitely go this way, the only alternative my eclipse sees is `com.google.gwt.thirdparty.guava.common.io.PatternFilenameFilter` implementing `java.io.FilenameFilter`, but then you have a new dependency and you write a Regex pattern which is far less readable and maintainable than your extensions. So I would stay with  `FileNameExtensionFilter` if this is really your use case.

Comment: My question really arises from the fact that the `FileNameExtensionFilter` class extends `javax.swing.FileFilter`, and does not implement *`FilenameFilter`*, which sounds more *correct*

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how it would be impractical. It shouldn't be appreciably slower than iterating over and adding to Lists instead of Set (although that would still be slightly faster and use less memory). But if you have a good reason to use a Set (e.g. you want unique elements and/or want fast queries for membership) I think you will be okay.

Though it is hard to say without looking at the rest of your code. I would suggest you test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested, you have the proper method to filter the set. The only think that I would do is to use `CollectionUtils.html#filter` from apache commons to make my code more readable and easy to maintain.